# Give somekind of signature/identifier to a Java process

Tags: java, linux, jvm, ps

Is there a way to start my `Java` process that I can easily identify it, from another program that runs a `ps` in the system?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a dummy system property using the `java` command line. This will be easily visible in a `ps`.

```
java ..... -Djvm.identifier=xyz
```

Comment: @Jim It is an ability of Java to supply system properties to the VM. So, every JVM must support this feature.

Answer (score 1):

```
java -Dvisualvm.display.name=wibble MyClass
```

Then you can find it with:

```
ps -ef | grep "visualvm.display.name=wibble"
```

If you use the `visualvm.display.name` property name then it will use that name when displaying your java processes in jvisualvm.

Comment: Is this applicable to all JVMs?

Comment: I think if the JVM supports jvisualvm (most do) then it should be applicable.